# Does setuptools build_ext behaves differently from distutils one?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

In short, replacing the distutils imports by the setuptools ones result in the shared library being produced in different places in an in-place build.

Here are the details. First the layout:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── simdlib
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── simd.c
    └── test.py
```

Then the setup.py script:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
#from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(name='simdlib',
      ext_modules=[Extension('simdlib/simd', ['simdlib/simd.c'])])
```

If I run python setup.py build_ext -i, then simd.so is produced in the simdlib directory.

But if I comment the first line of setup.py and uncomment the second line to replace distutils by setuptools, then simd.so is produced in the top directory and not inside simdlib as before. There is an extra line of output in that case:

```
copying build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/simdlib/simd.so ->
```

I have read in many places that setuptools could replace distutils, so I am confused.

I have encountered that problem with Python 2.7.9 and setuptools 3.6 (installed by virtualenv) on the one hand and with Python 3.4.3 and setuptools 12.05 (installed by pyvenv).

Answer (score 2):

So I debugged through the execution of setup.py and I just needed to write "simdlib.simd" instead of "simdlib/simd" for the name of the extension. The former works with Distutils too of course, so it's just that setuptools is not backward compatible here with the awkward former syntax.